# Where exactly does a thread hang in a ServerSocket.accept() during waiting for a connection?

Tags: java, serversocket

In the block below, I understand that this main thread is blocking and is therefore not listening for interruptions from other threads but does that mean that it literally hangs on the ServerSocket.accept() line?

```
        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(8080);

        while(true){ // Block until accept
            Socket acceptedSocket = serverSocket.accept(); // Give accepted socket OR NULL SOCKET to acceptedSocket

            handle(acceptedSocket);

            serverSocket.close();
        }
```

I am asking because I can't understand where it would be getting hanged up on the accept (ServerSocket.java):

```
public Socket accept() throws IOException {
        if (isClosed()) // No its open
            throw new SocketException("Socket is closed");
        if (!isBound())   // No its bound to 8080
            throw new SocketException("Socket is not bound yet");
        Socket s = new Socket((SocketImpl) null);                  // Create a null socket
        implAccept(s);                                          // Here???
        return s;
    }
```

ServerSocket.java again:

```
protected final void implAccept(Socket s) throws IOException {


  SocketImpl si = null;
    try {
        if (s.impl == null)
          s.setImpl();
        else {
            s.impl.reset();
        }
        si = s.impl;
        s.impl = null;
        si.address = new InetAddress();
        si.fd = new FileDescriptor();
        getImpl().accept(si);    // I'm thinking its here but when I look at this accept, thats an abstract method and don't know where to dig deeper.
```

Comment: It does not hang in accept(), it is waiting. Hanging is due to a bug; accept() is waiting for a connection. This is why multithreading is used if the server has to be active somewhere else.

Comment: "_// I'm thinking its here but when I look at this accept, thats an abstract method and don't know where to dig deeper._" – You can use your IDE to find implementations of the abstract method. However, I suspect eventually you'll run into a native method call. It's also possible only the implementation for your particular platform is present.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends on the OS, but on Linux, [accept()](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/accept.2.html) is a kernel call.  The most straighforward Java implementation would be to use that kernel call.

So the process is 'waiting in the kernel', loosely speaking.

Comment: Ok so ServerSocket.java  getImpl().accept(si);   --> That leads to the kernel call?

Comment: almost certainly, though I have not examined the code.